# Inserting a picture in the correct position

Tags: excel, vba, image

I'm using a code that inserts a picture (column A) of the corresponding item number located in Column B.

Current positioning of the picture:

[image: Current positioning of the picture]

However, the pictures that are inserted are located in the top left corner of each cell and I'd like to have them **in the center** of the cell **a little below the cell line** (cell size is 54 and picture is 50).

Here's the code that I use:

```vb
Sub InsertImageFullName()

On Error Resume Next

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim path$, cl As Range, myPicture As Object

Set Rng = Range("A2:A300")

cell_h = Range("A2").Top - Range("A1").Top 

For Each cl In Rng
  path = cl.Offset(0, 8).Value 
  If path Like "*?*" Then
    Set myPicture = ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(path) 
    With myPicture 
      .ShapeRange.LockAspectRatio = msoTrue 
      .Height = 50 
      .Top = Rows(cl.Row).Top
      .Left = Columns(cl.Column).Left
    End With
  End If
  Set myPicture = Nothing
Next 

End Sub
```

What needs to be modified to make this work ?

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: You need to remove `On Error Resume Next`. This line hides **all** error messages but the errors still occur, you just cannot see their messages. If you don't see them, you cannot fix them, if you don't fix them your code does not work. Remove that line and fix all your errors. You might benefit from reading [VBA Error Handling – A Complete Guide](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-error-handling).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To set the position of the picture you youst need to adjust the top and left position of it.

```
.Top = Rows(cl.Row).Top
.Left = Columns(cl.Column).Left
```

So you just need to add something. So if your cell height is `54` and your picture height is `50` and your picture should be centered the amount you need to add calculates like `add = (CellHeight - PictureHeight) / 2` which is `(54 - 50) / 2` which is `2` so you need to add `2` to the `.Top` position:

```
.Top = Rows(cl.Row).Top + 2 'add 2 to the top position of your picture.
```

Answer (score 0):

You know image width and height by `myPicture.Width` and `myPicture.Height`. And cell width and height by `cl.Width` and `cl.Height`

Image top position is `Cell top + (Cell top - Image Height) / 2`
And image left position is `Cell left + (Cell left - Image Width) / 2`

So you need to Change your code from

```
    .Top = Rows(cl.Row).Top
    .Left = Columns(cl.Column).Left
End With
```

To

```
    .Top = cl.Top + (cl.Height - myPicture.Height) / 2
    .Left = cl.Left + (cl.Width - myPicture.Width) / 2
End With
```

Comment: That did the job ... Thanks so much !

Answer (score -1):

Try to use [Vertical Alignment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.cellformat.verticalalignment) and [Horizontal Alignment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.cellformat.horizontalalignment) on Range object to align content of a cell properly.